# HTML5 Modal Window not working in IE or Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, modal-dialog

On the page http://canadianwhoswho.ca/order-subscribeonline.php I have created a modal window that opens when users click http://canadianwhoswho.ca/order-subscribeonline.php#openModal.  This works perfectly in Firefox, but not in IE or Chrome.  Instead, it just adds the modal text to the top of the page.

Here is the CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #E4E4E4;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#E4E4E4, #F6F6F6);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#E4E4E4, #F6F6F6);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#E4E4E4, #F6F6F6);
}

.close {
background: #E4E4E4;
color: #922211 !important;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { 
background: #922211;
color: #E4E4E4 !important;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Thank you for your interest in <em>Canadian Who's Who</em></h2>
    <p>To place an order, please contact us at <a href="mailto:info@canadianwhoswho.ca?subject=Order%20Canadian%20Who's%20Who">info@canadianwhoswho.ca</a>, or call <a href="tel:+17053255552">705-325-5552</a>.</p>
</div>
```

```
<a href="#openModal">Choose</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found similar answer on http://cameronbaney.com/2012/07/26/pure-html5css3-responsive-modal-window/

I have tried it and works for all three IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Hope it helps.